# How to update database column values in a single command(no CASE/SWITCH)?

Tags: sql, database

Lets say we have a table name Swap-Table.

```
    *Input Table*

    ID  NAME    Type
    ------------------ 
    1   name1    a
    2   name2    b
    3   name3    b
```

I want to write a single command to update the table.The output table would be

```
   **Output Table**

    ID  NAME    Type
    ------------------ 
    1   name1    b
    2   name2    a
    3   name3    a
```

Condition: No CASE/SWITCH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I only offer this as a "cute" way to do this transformation, rather than anything I'd allow (or even recommend) in production code:

```
declare @t table (ID int not null,Name varchar(17) not null,Type varchar(3) not null)
insert into @t(ID,NAME,Type) values
(1,'name1','a'),
(2,'name2','b'),
(3,'name3','b')
update @t set Type = CHAR(195-ASCII(Type))

select * from @t
```

Produces:

```
ID          Name              Type
----------- ----------------- ----
1           name1             b
2           name2             a
3           name3             a
```

(Different database products may have different ways to transform from/to ascii codes and for table variables)

Comment: Will it work for other column value which are not single alphabet? like,if we would swap between 'horse' and 'cow'

Answer (score 5):

You may use CTE or some sort of subquery to generate an update dictionary

```
WITH upd_dict (type_from, type_to) AS (
  SELECT 'a', 'b'
  UNION 
  SELECT 'b', 'a')
UPDATE table_name
   SET type = ud.type_to
  FROM upd_dict ud
 WHERE ud.type_from = type
```

But CASE looks much more readable and understandable here if you ask.